# Spring mvc can not get the form param

Tags: java, spring

Below is my code, and always get null for query method, i do not know why this happen. I can get the form param by other ways, such as @RequestParam etc. Do i need to set configuration for the Phone Class in the XML file? if so, how can i configure Phone Class in XML? My XML is recharge-servlet.xml.

Below is the Controller:

```
package com.nu.template.recharge;

import org.springframework.stereotype.Controller;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMethod;
import org.springframework.web.servlet.ModelAndView;


@Controller
@RequestMapping("/mobile")

public class XJMobile {

    @RequestMapping(value = "/index", method = RequestMethod.GET)
    public ModelAndView getIndexPage() {
        ModelAndView mav = new ModelAndView("recharge");
        return mav;
    }


    @RequestMapping(value = "/query", method = RequestMethod.POST)
    public String query(Phone phone) {
        System.out.println(phone.getNumber());

        return "helloworld";
    }   

}
```

Form:

```
<form action="query" method="POST" name="phone_form">
    <section>
        <label>phone:</label>
        <input type="text" name="phone_number" />
    </section>

    <input type="submit" value="submit">
</form>
```

Phone Class:

```
package com.nu.template.recharge;

public class Phone {
    private String phone_number;

    public String getNumber() {
        return this.phone_number;
    }

    public void setNumber(String phone_number) {
        this.phone_number = phone_number;
    }
}
```

recharge-servlet.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
xmlns:mvc="http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc"
xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans      http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans.xsd
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/context http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context.xsd
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc/spring-mvc.xsd">

<mvc:annotation-driven />

<context:component-scan base-package="com.nu.template.recharge"/>

<bean id="viewResolver" class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.InternalResourceViewResolver">
   <property name="prefix" value="/WEB-INF/view/"/>
   <property name="suffix" value=".jsp"/>
</bean>
```

Comment: shouldn't the form action be "mobile/query"?

Comment: @ Tony Vu But if the path of form action has problem, i do not think i can get param by @RequestParam either, right?

Comment: Also, your property (i.e. getter/setter) is named `number`, not `phone_number`. That doesn't match with the input name.

Comment: @JB Nizet the getter/setter must named using phone_number? i use number because when i check online resources, people write like this: public void setStudentID(studentID) {this.studentID = studentID;}, the name after set start with capital S, it is different from studentID, so i think i can use any name for setter/getter. i will rename, and try it again

Comment: Your getters/setters are fine. The problem is that the setter is `setNumber()`, and it's supposed to be called for an input field (and thus a parameter) named `phone_number`. That clearly doesn't match. So the setter should be `setPhone_number()`, or better, the input should be named `number`.

Comment: @JB Nizet i get the value when i change the setter to setPhone_number( ), thank you.

Answer (score 0):

You can get your Phone object initialized by

```
@RequestMapping(value = "query", method = RequestMethod.POST)
public String query(@RequestParam("phone_number") Phone phone) {
    System.out.println(phone.getNumber());

    return "helloworld";
}
```

Spring generally looks for same parameter type for binding or you can tell it to bind with your pojo, given a setter method which accepts parameter type.